# Error upgrading to CakePHP 4.5 from 4.4.6

Tags: cakephp

Upgrading my project from 4.4.6 to 4.5 in preparation for upgrading to 5.0.

I'm getting this error in the error.log:

Request URL: /users/login?redirect=%2F
2023-12-02 09:26:24 error: [Error] Call to protected method Cake\View\View::addHelper() from scope Cake\View\Helper in /home/jhogarth/tmp/Programming/members/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/Helper.php on line 119

On the web page, the only information displayed is: An Internal Server Error Occurred

There is no call to addHelper or loadHelper in my code for this project.

So far, I've run the upgrade tool several times to update the project.

Any suggestions for finding/fixing this issue?

TIA

Comment: Are you using 4.5.1? Make sure to use the latest patch release as it could contain critical fixes.

Comment: Also, the message rather indicates that a plugin or project code element is doing this call, which is invalid from inside a helper as such (as the message says). Follow the strack trace maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by creating a clean install of 4.5.1, copying the vendor code to my project, and re-installing all components: Authentication, Authorization, Bootstrap, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use version 4.5.3 and I also have this error when using the addHelper method for views built in the controller

```
$view = new View(); 
$view->addHelper('Resources');
```

So I still use the original loadHelper() method

```
$view = new View();
$view->loadHelper('Resources');
```

Migration changes this parameter in the application even though the View object does not have access to this method.

```
php bin/cake.php upgrade rector --rules cakephp45 /var/www/html/src/
```

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-5-migration-guide.html

> It is recommended to replace loadHelper() with new addHelper() method to add helpers in View::initialize()

So this proposed change only affects main views per controller. Not for dynamically built ones.